# passing linked list to function by value

Tags: c, pointers, pass-by-reference, singly-linked-list, pass-by-value

**EDIT:** my struct is of the form:

```
         struct node{
             int key;
             struct node* next;
         }
         typedef struct node* LIST;
```

I'm writing a function, called `print_list_iteratively`, which takes a singly linked list and prints its elements in reverse order iteratively. Let me put my 3 functions below and then explain what's my problem with them?

```
         LIST reverse_list(LIST L) {
              LIST current = L, prev = NULL, subsequent = NULL;
              while (current != NULL) {
                // first we need to get the next element to not lose the link.
                subsequent = current->next;

                // now reverse the pointer
                current->next = prev;

                // we need to update our prev to create link between the currrent and next element.
                // in short, we need to get the address of current node
                prev = current;

                // finally update the current
                current = subsequent;
             }
             return (L = prev);
        }
```

The above code reverses the list L, and returns the new head of the list L.

```
        void print_list(LIST L) {
             while (L) {
                printf("%d  ", L->key);
                L = L->next;
             }
        }
```

`print_list` prints the elements of the list in the order they've been connected.

I've all needed to write the `print_list_iteratively` function I mentioned at the beginning.

```
        void print_list_iteratively(LIST l) {
            // first reverse the list, then call print_list. that's all.
            printf("address of function parameter is %p\n", l);
            l = reverse_list(l);
            print_list(l);
        }
```

I've no problem with these functions; they work as expected, but the notion of pass by value and pass by reference confused me, when I tried to understand how the function takes list as a parameter and returns it. Let me simply write a main for testing these and we'll see how things get mixed.

```
         int main(void) {
             l = insert(l, 5);
             l = insert(l, 10);
             l = insert(l, 15);
             l = insert(l, 45);
             print_list(l);
             print_list_iteratively(l);
             print_list(l);
             return 0;
         }
```

when first `print_list` function is called, it prints `5->10->15->45.` Next `print_list_iteratively` is called on list `l`, which in its turn calls `reverse_list` and `print_list` in the body of the function. The `print_list` inside `print_list_iteratively` give reversed list `45->15->10->5.` Eventually, `print_list` inside main prints `5.`
I want to know why has second `print_list` just printed `5`? I've send list to `print_list_iteratively` pass by value, not pass by referce, despite this it's changed my original list insinde `main` function. Can somebody explain me how the lists in this example are passed to functions and how they're returned from them? I appreciate your answers.

Comment: `current->next = prev;` That code changes the original list. You passed the head pointer by value but it doesn't stop the list fields from being changed.

Comment: `typedef struct node* LIST;` hiding pointers behind a typedef leads to confusing code. It looks like you're passing in a value, but you're passing in a pointer. I'd suggest changing it to `typedef struct node LIST;` and passing in `LIST *`.

Comment: As a matter of style: do not hide pointers in typedefs, so use `typedef struct node LIST;`. Capital words are often reserved for macros, so rename `LIST` to for example `tList`.

Comment: @kaylum, thank you, got it. Let me ask one more question on passing head of list by value. In my procedure, reverse_list, I take head of original list by value and assign it to L, but this assignment just copies the value of head pointer to L. List L is the same as the list in my main function, but since I don't send the address of my original list, L doesn't point to the where original list points. BUT, when the operation is done, head was affected by changes in the function because initially they both have the same head values.

Comment: @kaylum, Function did operation on this address, this's is the reason my original list has changed, right? It would be nice to get your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you pass the head pointer by value. This lets your program to modify your linked list, but the head pointer remains the same.

You should pass the head pointer to the function by reference or a pointer which points to your pointer. (`node*& or node**`)
Keep in mind, if you pass it by pointer, you need to dereference it, when it is needed.